# Numerical recipes: How to pass function as argument of function newt in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers, newtons-method

My question is related to numerical recipes.
I have a global function which computes the vector of functions to be minimized

```
VecDoub vecfunc(VecDoub_I x) {
  // code is here
}
```

In a class function *run*, I tried to call the Numerical Recipes function newt, which reads my function *vecfunc* as shown,

```
class A {
    void run() {
        VecDoub_IO pt;
        pt.resize(2);
        pt[0] = 0.5;
        pt[1] = 0.5;
        bool check = false;
        newt<VecDoub>(pt, check, &vecfunc);
    }
}
```

Function *newt* is declared as

```
template <class T>
void newt(VecDoub_IO &x, Bool &check, T &vecfunc)
```

Why do I get the following compiler error?

```
error C2664: 'newt' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'VecDoub (__cdecl *)(VecDoub_I)' to 'VecDoub &'
```

Comment: InRe the title question: there is the c way with function pointers, the c++03 way with functors and the c++11 way with lambdas. I could get through the first two with a little thought and maybe some trial and error, but I'm hoping a pro will be along to compare and contrast all three...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calling `newt` you explicitly specify that `T` is `VecDoub`(You specified `newt<VecDoub>`) but you pass address of a function to it, so compiler can't convert your function to `VecDoub&`. If you want a `VecDoub&` in `newt` then call `vectfunc` and store it in a temporary variable and then pass that variable to the function(since in `newt` last parameter is a reference to `T`) but if you really need a function in `newt` then why you write `newt<VecDoub>(pt, check, &vecfunc)` while you can write `newt(pt, check, &vecfunc)` and let C++ deduce the type for you? and beside that in order to receive functions in `newt` do not get them by reference, instead get them by value, so `newt` shall be declared as:

```
template <class T>
void newt(VecDoub_IO &x, Bool &check, T vecfunc)
```

Since functions are usually small objects or pointers this will work and do not decrease performance

Answer (score 1):

Because you're supposed to call the function and pass the return value as parameter, not the function itself.

```
newt<const VecDoub>(pt, check, vecfunc(something) );
```

I added the `const` because the reference needs to be constant, otherwise the return value from `vecfunc` can't bind to it, because it's a temporary.

To explain:

```
newt<VecDoub>(pt, check, &vecfunc);
```

attempts to call a function similar to

```
newt_VecDoub(VecDoub_IO &x, Bool &check, VecDoub &vecfunc);
```

The third parameter you attempt to pass is `&vecfunc` which has the type `VecDoub (__cdecl *)(VecDoub_I)`, so it obviously can't work.